# De Duping Existing Records

Tags: dupeblocker

I am Having more duplicates in my org.I am not interested in paid app exchange products.Please, can you help me out to De-Dupe Existing Records?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&language=en_US&type=0) to have the system help you find existing duplicates (they'll be tagged), which you can then create reports on to find and merge/delete the duplicates. It's available in Professional Edition or higher, so you should be able to use this feature at no extra cost, and without installing any third-party packages.

Comment: Duplicate Management will prevent us to create Duplicate records.may i know how to delete duplicate records or how to merge the duplicate records.

Comment: @NaveenDhanaraj Yes, it can be configured to Block the creation of new records, and even notify administrators when duplicate records are created. Feel free to set up a sandbox or developer edition and experiment with this feature before enabling in production.

Comment: @NaveenDhanaraj To merge them, run the report, then go to each record and manually merge them. It's also possible to write a script to automate that, but I'd suggest that you use that cautiously, as you might end up deleting data that's not actual duplicates.

Comment: How to create Reports for Duplicate Records,Can you tell me filter criteria

Comment: @NaveenDhanaraj See [Create Custom Report Types for Duplicate Record Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&type=0&language=en_US) for more information.

Comment: Thank You for your time.I will create reports and I will get back to you.